# Update and Package Installation impossible: E: Unable to locate package! Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I have a problem.

Installing packages or updating the system is impossible.

Neither the Terminal nor the Software Manager are working (Software Manager dosn't start).

Terminal shows commands as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'non-free' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

When I try to install a program:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package exfat-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'exfat-utils' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package exfat-fuse

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
E: Type 'non-free' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.


sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package autokey-gtk
```

The content of my sources list file is as follows:

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.3 _Rosa_ - Release amd64 20151128]/ trusty contrib 

main non-free

deb http://xnv4.xandros.com/xs2.0/upkg-srv2 etch main contrib
      non-free

deb http://xnv4.xandros.com/xs2.0/upkg-srv2 etch main contrib
      non-free
```

This problem has occurred on my previous Linux Mint (17.0) and reoccurred a few weeks after installing LM 17.3.

Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate!

Comment: Have you updated or changed your package sources from the base install ones?

Comment: please edit your question and add the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.  the error message is telling you where the problem is, in line 3.  without seeing `sources.list`, my guess is that you've somehow added an extra line-feed to line 2 so the end of line 2 ("non-free") is now on line 3 by itself....or something very much like that.

Comment: I didn't edit anything - knowingly.

Comment: When I try to change my package sources, I get an error as followed:

Comment: Could not download all repository indexes
E: Type 'non-free' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: Unable to lock the list directory

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/163364/joe and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/163363/joe.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Your `sources.list` is incorrectly formatted. 'non-free' should not appear on a separate line. That's the reason you are seeing:

```
E: Type 'non-free' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The sources.list should look as follows:

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.3 _Rosa_ - Release amd64 20151128]/ trusty main contrib non-free

deb http://xnv4.xandros.com/xs2.0/upkg-srv2 etch main contrib non-free

deb http://xnv4.xandros.com/xs2.0/upkg-srv2 etch main contrib non-free
```

Note also that your first line is commented out, so you effectively only have two lines, neither of which look like standard sources for Mint. You probably want to add more sources. Also consider whether you want to keep the `xnv4.xandros.com` sources.