# I am having problems running updates and downloading software in terminal

Tags: permissions, apt, environment-variables, upgrade

Everytime I try and update my software this is what is says...

```
mint@mint ~ $ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `mint` user does not have permissions to execute the `apt-get` command.

Try running the following command instead.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: `jesuscoins@PCME ~ $ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jesuscoins: 
E: Type '**' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
jesuscoins@PCME ~ $`    So this is what I got in return...

Comment: You now have a different question, one that has already been asked here long since at the likes of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272704/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198460/ .